# What is a class monitor in D?

Tags: class, synchronization, monitor, d

D2.0 classes have a `__monitor` class property that "gives access to the class object's monitor" ([documentation](http://www.digitalmars.com/d/2.0/class.html)). I searched around a bit and did not find any information except for [this](http://www.digitalmars.com/d/2.0/changelog.html#new2_016) bit of detail. So: what is a monitor? Why is one monitor used for all [synchronized member functions](http://www.digitalmars.com/d/2.0/class.html#synchronized-functions)? Is it a  [synchronization primitive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monitor_%28synchronization%29) used for synchronizing member functions similar to Java? And why is the `__monitor` property in the language def if you are not supposed to use it / what are the use-cases?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The monitor is a lazily initialized object that all synchronized methods synchronize on, just like in Java.  Unlike Java, D is a systems programming language and exposes lower level details of how things work just in case you need to hack them, even if doing so is *usually* a bad idea.  This allows you to customize behavior.  For example, it is possible to customize the monitor object of a class, or to use a `core.sync.mutex` that shares a monitor with the class that owns it.

Comment: Thanks. So, if I look at `object.d`, I see an interface `Object.Monitor` (aka `IMonitor`) for this monitor. This is what I have to implement? And if I look at `core.sync.mutex`, I see a sample usage (in the comments something like `// NOTE: With DMD this can be "o.__monitor = &m_proxy".`). Correct?

Comment: @stephan:  I'm not sure, I've never actually had to mess with this before, so i don't know the details of it.

Comment: You shouldn't have to ever implement the monitor or set it yourself unless you're doing something *very* strange.  I've used the various synchronisation primitives in D a few times and never had to do anything of the sort.